# Teensy 3.2 Hellokeypad sketch compile errors

Tags: keypad, teensy

I'm getting a compiler error when I try and compile the HelloKeypad demo sketch.

I'm on a Windows 7 machine using a Teensy 3.2 board.

I bought a keypad like this one: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1824

I downloaded the keypad.zip file from here: 
https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Keypad.html
and I'm using the example sketch from the same web page:

```
/* @file HelloKeypad.pde
|| @version 1.0
|| @author Alexander Brevig
|| @contact alexanderbrevig@gmail.com
||
|| @description
|| | Demonstrates the simplest use of the matrix Keypad library.
|| #
*/
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {8, 7, 6}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key){
    Serial.println(key);
  }
}
```

Here is the compiler message.

```
Arduino: 1.6.6 (Windows 7), TD: 1.26, Board: "Teensy 3.2 / 3.1, Serial + Keyboard + Mouse + Joystick, 96 MHz optimized (overclock), US English"

In file included from C:\Users\FRESH1~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_827e3ed6878980f03915bd59f832243c\HelloKeypad.ino:10:0:
C:\Users\fresh1011\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad/Keypad.h:80:27: error: expected class-name before '{' token
class Keypad : public Key {
^
C:\Users\fresh1011\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad/Keypad.h:90:2: error: 'Key' does not name a type
Key key[LIST_MAX];
^
C:\Users\fresh1011\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad/Keypad.h:95:2: error: 'KeyState' does not name a type
KeyState getState();
^
C:\Users\fresh1011\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad/Keypad.h:119:28: error: 'KeyState' has not been declared
void transitionTo(byte n, KeyState nextState);
^
Multiple libraries were found for "Keypad.h"
 Used: C:\Users\fresh1011\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\teensy\avr\libraries\Keypad
exit status 1
Error compiling.
```

Is the Keypad.zip file out of date?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Arduino IDE 1.6.3 instead of 1.6.6.

According to the following [post](https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/31621-Matrix-keypad-compile-error) in the [pjrc forum](https://forum.pjrc.com/) it solves the problem for the library support.